# MySQL service was shut down - why?

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2

I have installed MySQL Server 5.5 on the WIndows Server 2008 R2. In the `services.msc` I see that it has the Startup `Type option` set to `Automatic`. Everything was fine until today when that service was somehow turned off, but I did not do this.

So,

1) what can makes that service to be shutted down ?

2) Maybe is there any error log ?

3) Is it possible to set that service to be automatically turned on if that situation will come again ?

Comment: What do your logs say ?

Answer (score 0):

1 - It could be many different things, I'd check your MySQL Log file in the first instance.

2 - ^^^ but also -> http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722404.aspx

3 - Yes, you can choose what you want a service to do if it fails;

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753662.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem too. Installed WAMP perfectly. Worked for about a month without having any issue. Then one day suddenly got this issue. What I did was just disabled my Antivirus application and everything started working normally. You may also have installed or updated your antivirus or firewall which is blocking your MySQL port. Try disabling it or add an exception in your firewall for this service. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

## SOLVED

I was viewing log entries and I saw that entry

```
IP address '..some IP...' has been resolved to the host name '..some name...',
which resembles IPv4-address itself.
```

or  `IP address '....' could not be resolved: Unknown host.`

I have reconfigured my MySQL server to reject TCP/IP connections by editing the `my.ini` config file

```
...
[mysqld]
...
skip-networking
shared-memory
...
```

as a tip - if you're trying to connect for that server via localhost in the .NET application, add `Connection Protocol=SharedMemory;` in the connection string.

No it's working. I think that was the reason why my MySQL service was stopped - someone was trying to connect to the serwer via TCP/IP and somehow it caused the service crash. DDOS ? Some login/password injection for connection ? I don't know that. Maybe there is a bug for that scenario on windows or something.